# Can't use Property Wrappers on a class marked with @Observable

Tags: swift, macros, observable, property-wrapper

I have a class which is similar to:

```swift
final class Person {
    @Resettable var name = "John Doe"
    
    func revertName() {
        name = $name
    }
}

@propertyWrapper
struct Resettable<T> {
    var wrappedValue: T
    let projectedValue: T
    
    init(wrappedValue: T) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue
        self.projectedValue = wrappedValue
    }
}
```

However, when I annotate `Person` with the new `@Observable` macro I got the following error:

> Property wrapper cannot be applied to a computed property

I'm assuming this happens because the `@Observable` macro adds a getter and setter to all properties in a class.

Is there any way I can use my `@Resettable` property wrapper and the `@Observable` macro at the same time?

*Context: In my case it's `class GameScene: SKScene` and I use `@Resettable` to reset things like `var runningSpeed` and whatnot. The game scene must be marked with `@Observable` because the `GameScene` is modified using a SwiftUI view called `GameSettingsView`. This view uses `@Bindable` and `@Observable` to modify the game scene.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - `@Observable` turns the stored properties into computed properties, so you cannot put property wrappers on them.

You can try turning your property wrapper also into a macro. For your `Resettable`, this is rather simple. You just generate a new property, prefixed with `$` with the same initialiser.

A simple implementation I wrote (I'm rather bad at using SwiftSyntax, so please excuse me)

```
public enum Resettable: PeerMacro {
    public static func expansion(of node: AttributeSyntax, providingPeersOf declaration: some DeclSyntaxProtocol, in context: some MacroExpansionContext) throws -> [DeclSyntax] {
        // only apply to vars
        guard let varDecl = declaration.as(VariableDeclSyntax.self),
            varDecl.bindingSpecifier.text == "var" else {
            return []
        }
        return varDecl.bindings.filter {
            // apply only to those with initialisers
            $0.initializer != nil && 
            // and also the name of the variable does not start with underscore
            !$0.pattern.as(IdentifierPatternSyntax.self)!.identifier
                .text.starts(with: "_") 
        }.map {
            return "let $\($0.pattern) = \($0.initializer!.value)" as DeclSyntax
        }
    }
}

@main
struct ResettablePlugin: CompilerPlugin {
    let providingMacros: [Macro.Type] = [Resettable.self]
}

// ...

@attached(peer, names: prefixed(`$`))
public macro Resettable() = #externalMacro(module: "SomeModule", type: "Resettable")
```

Notes:

- I had to filter out the variables whose name start with underscore, because `@Observation` apparently generates a `@Resettable var _name`, and we don't want to add a `$_name`.
- The initialiser will be run twice, so make sure it doesn't have side effects.